# How to implement business rules before calling Sales Force REST APIs

Tags: rest-api

I am new to SalesForce and would like to know if we can have wrapper around SF REST APIs to add business rules?

Before passing SF REST API parameters we would like to apply some business rules and change value of parameters based on business rules.

Here is scenario, we  would like to exchange data between SF and other applications and we would like to use SF out of box REST APIs (few of them are listed below). Can we have wrapper around following API’s for applying few business rules (example, identifying requesting source, Once we get request from non-SF application, rules to identifying customer type (we have different customer types and each one has little different treatment etc. ) and then pass SF API required parameters,

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/
SObject Basic Information 
SObject Rows by External ID 
SObject Blob Retrieve
SObject Rows

Thanks

-vinay

Comment: Just to be sure I'm understanding this properly, you're trying to make a REST api call from an outside system to Salesforce. You then want to identify the source and do some business logic on the Salesforce side?

Comment: That's right. You got it correct.

Answer (score 2):

It will probably be extremely tricky to return custom data using GET with the built in Salesforce REST Api.

Salesforce does allow you to create custom Salesforce web services which will be very useful for your situation. Instead of hitting the normal Rest API, you can hit a link similar to this

> https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/CustomOpportunity

You can create GET, POST, PUT, DELETE calls for the class

You would build a Apex class similar to this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CustomOpportunity/*')  
global with sharing class RESTOpportunityController {

    @HttpGet   
    global static List<Opportunity> getOpportunity() {
        String customerType = RestContext.request.params.get('customerType');

        // Add custom logic before your query
        List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT AccountId, Amount, CampaignId, CloseDate, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Description, ExpectedRevenue, Fiscal, FiscalQuarter, FiscalYear, ForecastCategory, ForecastCategoryName, HasOpportunityLineItem, Id, IsClosed, IsDeleted, IsPrivate, IsWon, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastReferencedDate, LastViewedDate, LeadSource, Name, OwnerId, Pricebook2Id, Probability, StageName, SystemModstamp, TotalOpportunityQuantity, TrackingNumber__c, Type FROM Opportunity]

        //Add more custom logic here
        return opportunities;    
    }
}
```

You can get more documentation from Salesforce here
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is helpful. I will go through document link you sent and try to understand more.

Comment: Let me know if you have a related question